# Emacs error with MobileOrg push

Tags: org-mode

I am trying to set Emacs org-mode to do the initial push of my files into the Dropbox folder, by running *org-mobile-push*, nonetheless I keep getting an error which reads **Invalid function: org-eval-in-environment**

I have searched the web for an answer, but have not been able to locate one.

In terms of this I have done the following:

- Reinstalled org-mode through Git, using the following commands:

  `mkdir $HOME/elisp && cd $HOME/elisp`

  `git clone git://orgmode.org/org-mode.git`

  `cd org-mode && make && make doc && make install`
- This installed correctly.

The *org-mobile-push* used to work fine with the version of org-mode that came with my install of Emacs 23.3 from http://emacsformacosx.com/, which I believe was on the version 6 branch of org-mode.

I later stopped using/testing the sync with MobileOrg, and moved along to update to version 7.7. through ELPA.

Following that, I started playing with creating a Git repo for my files.

Something along the line has apparently damaged an important configuration.

I am new to org-mode, Emacs and Git as well.

Any guiding will be appreciated. Lastly, if this seems all messed up, please provide some info on how to reset Emacs and org-mode to its "default version (as it came with 23.3)

Thanks,

Comment: A few things that might help find the answer/solution: 1) From in Emacs, could you run `M-x org-version`. 2) Is your git repository for your .emacs.d/ files or for your user files? 3) Could you include the .emacs.d/init.el or .emacs.d lines where you load org-mode (just to make sure it is pointing at the right version.

Answer (score 1):

Not exactly a solution, but if you've got a valid index.org file, you don't need org-mobile-push. mobileorg is perfectly happy to pull everything linked from a manually generated file.

If you'd prefer not to download every single org file there, every time, try:

```
cd /your/org/dir/
md5sum *.org >checksums.dat
```

It'll only pull the files that have changed checksums. I have it in a cron job.

Comment: Could you expand on what's a *valid index.org* file, and what it's meant to achieve, maybe ? As such, you're right, it's not exactly a solution, hardly even an answer.

Answer (score 0):

First make sure you don't have other versions of org visible to emacs (one version comes with emacs distribution, I always delete it). The version/architecture of emacs used to compile the sources matters as well. I had this exact error with org-mobile-push when I copied compiled org tree from Linux to Windows, so try recompiling org. One simple way to do that from within emacs is to open the org/lisp directory in dired, mark all the source files via "*. el" (sans the quotes), then byte-compile the files by pressing "B". Now reload org via its menu or via "C-c C-x !".